# STM32F4 (Nucleo-F446RE CooCOX) basic GPIO

Tags: arm, stm32f4

I just started programming the Nucleo-F446RE (Based on the STM32F446RE MCU).

I can't seem to get a pin to go active, I'm trying to just toggle a GPIO using the following code:

```
//*****************************************************************************
#include "stm32f446xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
//! \file main.c
//! \brief main application
//! \version 1.0.0.0
//! \date $Creat_time$
//! \author $Creat_author$
//! \copy
//!
//! Copyright (c) 2014 CooCox.  All rights reserved.
//
//! \addtogroup project
//! @{
//! \addtogroup main
//! @{
//*****************************************************************************

int main(void)

__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
     GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct;

     GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
     GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
     GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
     GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct);


    while(1)

    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(&GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct,GPIO_PIN_1);


    }
```

It doesn't seem to work though..I've gone through the header file and c file of the GPIO which explains how to go about setting the pin, although even following this to the bone, it just stays low. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you need a delay between toggles, this is way faster than the eye can see, and may even be too fast for the led to "glow".  put a delay in there a whole second or large fraction of...

Comment: if you want to see if your init code works take the while loop out, dont assume that making a pin high turns the led on, depends on the board design.  try once with one toggle, if the led doesnt come on and stay on the try a run with two toggles, if it still doesnt come on and stay on then your init isnt working, if it does then you need a delay

Comment: @old_timer I just connected it to an oscilloscope and tried it with the while, without the while and with one and two toggles. It doesn't output anything at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
    `HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(&GPIO_InitTypeDefStruct,GPIO_PIN_1);`

should have been

```
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_1);
```